# Spatial subsetting SpatialPolygonsDataFrames completely within selecting area using R

Tags: r, select-by-location, subset

I am trying to spatially subset in R:

- the **forest stand data** (many small polygons) by the
- **watershed** data (one polygon)

My datasets are both in `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` format. I don't want to **intersect** or **clip** the data, because this creates small polygons on the border. Instead, I would like to select polygons `completely within` or `within`, such `Select Layer By Location` tool in ArcGIS. The **output**, unlike in ArcGIS, **should be a new shapefile**.

Here is how it is looks like: 
forest stands = green, 
watershed: blue border, 
selected stands `completely within`: yellow.

[image: forests in watershed]

However, I cannot find, how to make this in R?

Using `sp::over(x = watershed, y = forest)` the output is a a data.frame, not a spatial feature. The tools `sf::st_within(x, y, sparse = TRUE, prepared = TRUE)` seems promissing, but they operates on `sf` objects, not on `spatialPolygonDataFrame`.

Is there any quick **spatial subset in R** solution that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**** Update (2019-10-15), I added a `spatial.select` function to the [spatialEco](https://github.com/jeffreyevans/spatialEco) package that emulates a spatial select in ArcGIS/Pro. The `predicate` argument controls the type of intersection (intersect", "contains", "covers", "touches", "proximity"). If `predicate = "proximity"` then the `distance` argument needs to be specified as well. This will return features within a specified distance. This is currently in the development version but will be on CRAN at a future date. You can install the development version using the remotes package: `remotes::install_github("jeffreyevans/spatialEco")` ****

Take a look at some of the identity functions in [rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) such as [gTouches](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gTouches), [gIntersects](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gIntersects), [gContains](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gContains), [gRelate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gRelate), [gWithin](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gContains), ect...

At their most basic, these functions can return a Boolean that will allow you to perform the equivalent of a spatial select. To control output, take a close look at the function(s) arguments and experiment a bit with outputs from various functions to ensure that your results are as expected. The specific function you choose depends on the application. This [Lin.ear th.inking blog](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html) gives some guidance on the different rgeos functions and insight to the [Dimensionally-Extended 9 Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) topology model that GEOS uses.

You do not want a "new spatial feature object" resulting from a given function, per se as this would represent an intersection of some sort. ArcGIS does not return a new feature either, just the subset query of spatially selected features within an existing feature class. You can use results from `rgeos` or the `sp::over` function to subset a new feature class based on an index query of the Boolean.

Here is a simple worked example.

Add packages and make example data

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
  p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))")
  p2 = readWKT("POLYGON((0.5 1,0 2,1 2,0.5 1))")
  p3 = readWKT("POLYGON((0.5 0.5,0 1.5,1 1.5,0.5 0.5))")
  p2 <- rbind(p2,p3, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)

plot(p1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,2))
  plot(p2,add=TRUE)
```

Here are the Boolean results from `gOverlaps`, note the byid = TRUE argument.

```
gOverlaps(p1, p2, byid=TRUE)
```

Now, we can wrap `which` in a row index query using `gOverlaps` to create the subset object and plot the result.

```
p2.over <- p2[which(gOverlaps(p1, p2, byid=TRUE)),]

plot(p1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,2))
  plot(p2.over, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you very much! Finally, the `gContains(watershed, forest, byid=TRUE)` was the correct one, to subset the all polygons within the watershed border. the `gOverlaps` selected only the polygons overlayed by the border line, not by the whole polygon.  To create new feature from the selection as `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, this worked well: `forest[which(gContains(watershed, forest, byid=TRUE)),]`